# Getting an iPhone 5 to use the 'correct' css rules

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, iphone-5

I'm trying to get our responsive web app to display correctly on iPhone 5 as part of a series of 'bug fixes'.

The app is applying the css rules for a larger screen which means text is over-sized and forces elements to overlap.

I have tried:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* css here */}
@media only screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) { /* css here */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* css here */ }
```

..as suggested by various answers here on SO. I have also tried all of these queries separated by commas.

**How do I force an iPhone 5 specifically (other iPhones seem to be rendering well enough) to use the smaller, intended text sizes?**

Comment: Check that [codepen](https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/XaKQJm). Set the media query to `min:319px` and `max:370px`. Check the responsiveness in the developer mode of your browser. Text and image is getting smaller when you hit 370px. Sometimes you need to use the `!important` Keyword in CSS to make it work. Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked your codepen; I already have a media query for widths less than 430px - which isn't getting applied; How would adding another in a range less than 430px work any better? I'll give it a go though, because I'm at a loss otherwise...

Comment: Did you try to copy paste my `@media` statement and set your CSS rules with the `!important` keyword? No changes? Because it has to work. Maybe you forgot a `}` or something because if it works on codepen it should work in your project as well. This @media querys can be tricky.....

Comment: I'm trying to get the new range applying on a media query that already exists - does the following look correct to you? ... @media only screen and (max-width: 430px), only screen and (min-width:319px) and (max-width:370px) { }  I haven't tried the app with '!important' yet, but that's only because I'm reluctant to have so many css rules use that. Also just because it works in codepen does not mean it will definitely work on an actual iPhone 5 - at least that's what I'm rapidly learning.

Comment: I've just realised the correct css rules ARE being applied! It's just that the text, for some reason, is being rendered much larger. There must be some quirk in the iPhone 5 that causes this over-sized rendering. I'll try to set an iPhone5-only media query that sets the base font-size to something smaller.